How can I add a wrapper around a CKEditor 5 table without breaking its features?
I'm currently trying to convert one of our older CKEditor to make it work in CKEditor 5. All the plugin needs to do is add a wrapper to any tables that are created in the editor.
I have successfully added the wrapper using a downcast, however it seems to be breaking any of the features that come with the Table and TableToolbar.
Here is the original code that I'm trying to convert from
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('tableWrapper', {

    init: function (editor) {

        editor.on('insertElement', function (event) {
            if (event.data.getName() === 'table') {
                var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass('tableWrapper');
                div.append(event.data);
                event.data = div;
            }
        }, null, null, 1);

    }
});

CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = "tableWrapper";

The new CKEditor 5 setup
import {
    ClassicEditor,
    Bold,
    Essentials,
    Heading,
    Italic,
    Paragraph,
    List,
    Table,
    TableToolbar,
    SourceEditing
} from 'ckeditor5';
import 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css';

import TableWrapper from "./TableWrapper.js";

ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        plugins: [Essentials, Paragraph, Heading, List, Bold, Italic, Table, TableToolbar, SourceEditing, TableWrapper],
        toolbar: ['heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'insertTable', 'sourceEditing'],
        table: {
            contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells']
        },
    })
    .then(editor => {
        console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.stack);
    });

and the new plugin code (TableWrapper.js)
import { Plugin } from 'ckeditor5';

export default class TableWrapper extends Plugin {
    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;
        this._defineConverters(editor);
    }

    pluginName() {
        return 'TableWrapper';
    }

    _defineConverters(editor) {
        editor.conversion.for('downcast').elementToStructure({
            model: 'table',
            view: (modelElement, { writer }) => {
                
                const tableElement = writer.createContainerElement( 'table', modelElement.getAttributes(), [
                    writer.createSlot()
                ] );

                const figureElement = writer.createContainerElement( 'figure', { class : 'table' }, [
                    tableElement
                ] );
                
                const wrappedElement = writer.createContainerElement("div", { class: 'tableWrapper' }, [figureElement]);

                return wrappedElement;
            },
            converterPriority: 'high'
        });
    }
}

This current code wraps the table as expected, though I lose all of the Table and TableToolbar features like being able to add/merge rows/columns
